# How to set focus to an Entity in the Entity Framework Designer when an on-click event is triggered?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-extensions, entity-framework-designer

I'm writing a Visual Studio Extension (VSPackage) which interacts with the Entity Framework. My extension currently consists of a ToolWindow with a UserControl as content. I can populate this UserControl with WPF Controls using WPF/XAML. 
I'm checking if the entities, in the edmx file that's currently open in the Designer, have all the Scalar Properties I need them to have. Else I'm adding an error to my errorlist saying: 'entity' is missing 'property'. I'm displaying this errorlist in a ListBox in my UserControl. 

I'd like to know if it's possible to automate the Entity Framework Designer in a way that it focuses the entity my error is about when I double click the error in the ListBox.